# Flutter: How to create Form using TextEditingController inside FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

After loading the data from _profileFuture, it sets the initial value, but whenever I try to edit the textformfield it just reloads the data with the initial value. Not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    _profileRepository = ProfileRepository();
    _profileFuture = _profileRepository.getProfileByUserId(_user!.uid);
  }




FutureBuilder(
    future: _profileFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            var profile = snapshot.data as Profile;
            _firstNameController.text = profile.firstName!;
            return ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'First Name',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _firstNameChanged = true;
                      });
                    },
                    validator: (name) {
                      if (isNameValid(name)) {
                        return null;
                      } else {
                        return 'Enter a valid first name';
                      }
                    },
                    autovalidateMode: _firstNameFocusNode.hasFocus && _firstNameChanged ? AutovalidateMode.always : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                    controller: _firstNameController,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    focusNode: _firstNameFocusNode,
                  )
                ]
            );
          }
          else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        }
    ),
```

**Update:** So I created a variable that I can check to  only set the controllers once when the page first loads and it seems to work, but there must be another way to handle forms if anyone has any other solutions:

```
if (!_isDataLoaded) {                                     
    _firstNameController.text = profile.firstName ?? "";
    _isDataLoaded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` rebuilds the tree. `onChanged` function of text field is called every time text in the `TextFormField` is changed.

So, basically this `_firstNameController.text = profile.firstName!;` is what's happening when the input text is changed.

The below function is causing the problem.

```dart
setState(() {
  _firstNameChanged = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that is what I thought, but how would I do a form in a futurebuilder the futurebuilder is constantly reloading the data? Should I not use a futurebuilder? and if not, what would I do? Thanks!

Comment: How is the form submitted? If there's a button, the validation may be done there.

Comment: Validation isn't the issue. The problem is I want an editable form to only be populated with initial values once, I don't want the form to be redrawn multiple times, overriding the data that a user may enter into the text fields. I could probably set a property after the initial load and check that property in the future method, but that seems like a rig... seems like there should be an easier solution for a simple form like this.

Comment: `_firstNameChanged` is being used at `autovalidateMode`. It's set at `onChanged` by `setState` which is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, but what I am saying is that the page is being reloaded numerous times, like when I bring the keyboard up, and other things, not just this onChanged event, so finding a solution for this onChanged event will not fix my problem.

Comment: Something else could be going on. Maybe a MRE of the page in question would make it clearer. But, Seems like you found a work around.